# Got error when starting elasticsearch, error saying Failed to bind transport port to 9093

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6

I got error like below in both servers. I setup 2 server for running elasticsearch. Config file also attached as below. I am using ubuntu 18.04.

I got error saying failed to bind transport port 9093. I changed default value. I there any other i need to change ?

I am using open jdk version 8 - 181 version and elasticsearch version 6.4.3

```
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,155][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,157][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,158][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 16777216, hard limit: 16777216
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,158][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example: 
    # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
    elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
    elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,158][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] If you are logged in interactively, you will have to re-login for the new limits to take effect.
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,304][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] initializing ...
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,401][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [linux-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [24.6gb], net total_space [28.9gb], types [ext4]
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,401][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [linux-1] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,402][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] node name [linux-1], node ID [h03oGLGESzqeHmeNJLl0LQ]
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,402][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] version[6.4.3], pid[11401], build[oss/deb/fe40335/2018-10-30T23:17:19.084789Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-1030-azure/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_181/25.181-b13]
[2018-11-11T12:38:21,403][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true,  -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=oss, -Des.distribution.type=deb]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,242][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [reindex]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [repository-url]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] loaded module [tribe]
[2018-11-11T12:38:22,243][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [linux-1] no plugins loaded
[2018-11-11T12:38:25,636][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [linux-1] using discovery type [zen]
[2018-11-11T12:38:26,235][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] initialized
[2018-11-11T12:38:26,235][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] starting ...
[2018-11-11T12:38:26,561][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [linux-1] Exception
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9093]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindToPort(TcpTransport.java:821) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:786) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:134) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:66) 

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
[2018-11-11T12:38:26,581][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [linux-1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9093]]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]

    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9093]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindToPort(TcpTransport.java:821) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:786) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]

    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[?:?]

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
[2018-11-11T12:38:27,284][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] stopping ...
[2018-11-11T12:38:27,288][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] stopped
[2018-11-11T12:38:27,288][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] closing ...
[2018-11-11T12:38:27,321][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [linux-1] closed
```

My config file for servers as below

Linux-1 server

```
cluster.name: linux-elk
node.name: linux-1
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10000
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 24.95.245.313
http.port: 9092
transport.tcp.port: 9093
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: 
     - 178.51.190.47
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Linux-2 server

```
cluster.name: linux-elk
node.name: linux-2
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10000
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 178.51.190.47
http.port: 9092
transport.tcp.port: 9093
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: 
     - 24.95.245.313
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

plese help ? what i need to do now ?

Comment: But if i change network.host to 0.0.0.0 in both nodes and start nodes, both working well. That time i don;t have this error ? 

So i don't think any other application using this port

Answer (score 0):

Another application may be bind to port 9093. need to check it first.

Comment: But if i change network.host to 0.0.0.0 in both nodes and start nodes, both working well. That time i don;t have this error ? 

So i don't think any other application using this port